# AWS EC2: Any reason not to always use the cheapest instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When setting up EC2 with Amazon Web Services, is there any reason not to always use  the cheapest instance (ie t2.nano - if you're going to be using *tx.x* based instances) and have it automatically scale up (note: UP, not OUT) to use what it requires?

Why start at a higher instance (eg. t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium) if you don't necessarily need it?

Is the only reason not to, to ensure there's no performance issues while scaling auto-adjusts?

Comment: Drive by downvote? Any particular reason?

Comment: AWS doesn't support automatic scale UP, only automatic scale OUT. Scaling UP requires shutting down the instance, changing the instance type, then starting the instance back up. Also if your server applications have any memory usage settings you may have to update those settings every time you scale your server up. Also you need to be very aware of how CPU credits work on T2 instances before you use them in any production workload.

Comment: Although what you're saying is true, if you have something configured inside an auto scaling group then you can very much do this without manual intervention. Though your app needs to support the transition of bringing new nodes in to the group and phasing old ones out.

Comment: @MarkB That explains a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems *automatically* scaling UP is [not available in AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html), and actually you have to scale OUT. With this in mind, it makes sense to always begin with the smallest instance that your app will run on well, which may not be the cheapest.

Answer (score -1):

It's all based on your application usage. If your testing something in AWS with EC2 instance the T2 family instance is pretty fine and you can go ahead and use it. For Production, you can go with following instance base on your application.

**Application usage:**

CPU bouns use C4 Family

Memory bouns use R4 or m3 family

Storage bouns use d2,i2, and i3 family

Kindly find the following link for your reference.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html

Answer (score -1):

Quite a broad question in my opinion as we know nothing about the underlying application so I'll give an example based on some assumptions on when it obviously wouldn't work.

I'm also assuming you're using auto scaling here and adding another instance type based on alarms and metrics?

For example if you had a single instance inside an autoscaling group for an important customer focused solution then for the duration that your system is potentially not serving requests quick enough because of the resource limit and while the scaling process is taking place then you're potentially losing custom and/or money. Especially if you've got to scale about 5 times to get to the right instance type.

Also, what's the bottleneck? If its network io then scaling through the T2 family won't help at all as you'd benefit from enhanced networking which is only supported on certain instances types. For general purpose you'd be wanting an m4 type.